# Nvidia driver update on ubuntu 18.04. 1 live usb.!

Tags: live-usb

I made a persistent usb (4gb) with unetbootin for Ubuntu 18.04. 1.
I booted once with nomodeset and updated my nvidia drivers.. But again after rebooting all settings are lost including new folders,nvidia driver and needed nomodeset again...

Where did things go wrong?

Comment: Someone please answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drivers on ubuntu 18.04.1 live usb.!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084171/drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-live-usb)

Comment: Grandfather Clause. Leave open.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia graphics drivers are not working on persistent drives, The video driver needs to load before the persistence file and that is not possible.

Nvidia drivers do work with a Full install to USB, Nvidia is now smart enough to not load the drivers on a computer that does not have an Nvidia card.

You need a bigger drive for a Full install, at least 8GB.

Step by step instructions are here: [How to keep files on usb after rebooting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080362/how-to-keep-files-on-usb-after-rebooting/1080474#1080474)