# Drivers on ubuntu 18.04.1 live usb.!

Tags: live-usb

I plan to use my live usb with persistence for Ubuntu without installing.. Made using unetbootin 
But I always need to set nomodeset to boot up. I updated nvidia drivers too but no use after reboot.. All drivers folders get deleted

I'm even unable to use persistent data.

Comment: @Uday P: please do not double post, One post per question is enough. Please see your other post about using Nvidia drivers with persistent boot.

Answer (score 1):

**Nvidia graphics drivers are not working on persistent drives**

The video driver needs to load before the persistence file and that is not possible.

Nvidia drivers **DO** work with a Full install to USB, Nvidia is now smart enough to not load the drivers on a computer that does not have an Nvidia card.

You need a bigger drive for a Full install, at least 8GB.

Step by step instructions are here: [How to keep files on usb after rebooting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080362/how-to-keep-files-on-usb-after-rebooting/1080474#1080474)

If all you need is to add nomodeset to your boot, edit grub.cfg, syslinux.cfg or txt.cfg similar thus:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu persistent" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash nomodeset persistent ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Just add the word **nomodeset** leave the rest of the text as you found it.

Comment: The problem is.. I have a laptop.. And I don't want to mess up the Hdd now.. So I want to use live usb.. When I used a persistent usb on desktop.. It saved files after rebooting..

Comment: This isn't working on my laptop... I need to boot using nomodeset always.. And files keep getting lost even if its persistence

Comment: @Uday P: What tool did you use for your persistent install? Unetbootin? mkusb? If a grub based install like mkusb, nomodeset can be added to grub.cfg, if a Syslinux based install nomodeset can be added to txt.cfg or syslinux.cfg, I will edit my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a "live" boot from your usb drive; this is not the same as an actual install of ubuntu (which is what you want to be able to customize, or use non-standard drivers, etc). A live boot with persistence only allows you to store data from boot to boot.

In essence, you can plug in your live usb stick, then insert another usb media, boot from live and choose to install to the other usb drive. That should do what you want.